# JavaScript Promise - Object defined but specific property undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, object, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get data from firebase. I receive the data as an Object and it shows the data I want. However when I try to get a specific value from an Object property it says it's undefined. What am I doing wrong or what am I missing?

```
export const createChat = () => {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: CREATE_SINGLE_CHAT });
    const creator = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    const userRef = firebase.database().ref(`/users/${creator}`);
    const currUser = await userRef.once('value');
    console.log(currUser);
    console.log(currUser.name);
  };
};
```

Here is the console.log:

```
23:30:58  // currUser
Object {
  "email": "a@b.de",
  "is24Hours": true,
  "name": "Alex",
}
23:30:58 // currUser.name
undefined
```

I'm using React Native with Redux and Redux-Thunk and also the realtime-database from firebase as database.

Comment: This is more of a firebase question. It's possible that the `currentUser` instance doesn't give direct access to its properties. Is there a getter you must use instead?

Comment: I thought it has nothing to do with firebase since I get the results I want from firebase as a whole object. As far as I know there is nothing like a getter I can use with the firebase javascript api.

Comment: Seems like you need to call val() method of the currUser, according to documentation to get the real data.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Comment: Thank you @MaxBrodin that was it. I can't believe how I forgot about that. Maybe it's too late for me. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Max Brodin mentioned I forgot to use the val() method from firebase:
[firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write](http://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write)

working code:

```
export const createChat = () => {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: CREATE_SINGLE_CHAT });
    const creator = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    const userRef = firebase.database().ref(`/users/${creator}`);
    const currUser = await userRef.once('value');
    console.log(currUser);
    console.log(currUser.val().name); // here is the change
  };
};
```